# How to write a basic neural network in tflearn for z = x/(x+y)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, linear-regression, tflearn

Being new to deep learning world and after reading a lot of theories, I was trying to understand how does the neural net learn practically, so I provided it with simple dataset where input columns are [[x,x+y]...] and output column [[x/(x+y)]...] and tried it using tflearn but even after countless tries(2 days) the network is not able to minimize loss. Even after it minimizes(after adding tanh layer) the network predictions are way off. Can someone help me with this? Below is the code.

```
neural_net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 2])

neural_net = tflearn.fully_connected(neural_net, 1, 
activation='linear', bias=True)
neural_net = tflearn.regression(neural_net, optimizer='sgd', 
learning_rate=0.001, loss='mean_square')
# train
model = tflearn.DNN(neural_net,tensorboard_verbose=3)
model.fit(OR, Y_truth, n_epoch=1000, 
snapshot_epoch=False,validation_set=0.1,batch_size=10)
print model.get_weights(neural_net.W)

# prediction
print model.predict([[2,2]])
```

The output prediction is 0.13946463!!

Comment: Do you mean output x/x+y or x/(x+y)? Because the former can be learned by a linear net, the latter can't.

Comment: Its actually x/(x+y). I know its a non-linear model and I have tried adding 2 non-linear layers. But I still feel like I am shooting in the dark, so is there any specific process for selecting hidden layers and their activations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network won't be able to learn that function.

The network has a single neuron. That's equivalent to ax+by+c where you try to learn a,b,c.

You need more non-linearity in your model. You need to add more layers and neurons with non-linear activation for the model to be able to learn your desired function.

Comment: How do I choose how many more hidden layers to add and which activation functions to choose. Can you please elaborate the process?

Comment: To add a new layer just add more lines like the one with tflearn.fully_connected. replace 1 with something higher to have more neurons on the layer. for the activation parameter replace 'linear' with 'sigmoid', 'tanh' or 'relu' (these are the common ones).

Comment: For determining which ones work best for you, you need to try different combinations. The process is called hyperparameter tuning and there are programs out there to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually got it to reduce loss to 0.00121 and predictions are also somewhat correct(workable! for now!). I added tanh layer with 16 neurons and a output linear layer. You were actually right non-linearity was needed. So accepting your answer!!